# html com jquery (tabs)

Tags: jquery, html

estou com um problema em colocar as tabs a funcionar.

Aparece-me os nomes das tabs mas não como deviam aparecer dentro de um rectangulo.
pois a seguir quero colocar os dados php lá dentro

http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3444/

PS: Tenho esse codigo a cima mas falta-me um pedaço de codigo para funcionar a tabs

```
 $("#tabs").tabs();
```

Comment: Amigo, existe muio "lixo" no código que você adicionou, faça uma limpeza nele deixando evidente apenas a parte das tabs que terei prazer em ajudá-lo. Até mais

Comment: o que quero é colocar a funcionar é o php e as tabs e no fim dessa pagina quero que tenha a paginação. http://jsfiddle.net/J5Sx4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você procura seria isso.

Cada tabs ira conter o conteudo que você precisa, quando for fazer o `fecth`, jã adicione em cada tabs o conteudo que precisa.

no link que abaixo segue sistema com TABS e CSS, para o meu `inline` e `Jquery` para quando clicar na TAB específica mudar o conteúdo.

[Codigo com Jquery e CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Franckcf/J5Sx4/1/)

Comment: fiquei com uma duvida. dentro desses tabs posso inserir php para mostrar dados ?

Comment: @user3253195, sim dentro das `TABS` você pode inserir o PHP para colocar o conteúdo, basta fazer como no outro código que fez, onde contem o `fetch`, para que o conteúdo apareça dentro da `TAB`que você deseja. A única coisa que precisa fazer é determinar qual `TAB` ira aparecer e quais ficarão escondidas.
Seu primeiro comentário não ficou muito claro, explique melhor. :-)

Comment: Entao se é apenas dentro das tabs que coloco o php como posso fazer a paginação? Quando eu fiz a paginação ficou tudo dentro de um php só

Comment: @user3253195 Seu `PHP` deve ficar [ASSIM](http://jsfiddle.net/Franckcf/PbZkV/1/).
Conforme ele buscar as informações no banco ele já coloca no `HTML` o que deve ser exibido em cada `TAB`. O `CSS` irá permanecer o mesmo, sendo assim exibindo o que deseja.